# DataTables warning:

Tags: jquery, html

DataTables warning: table id=tbexport - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is to allow the destroy when you reinitialise the datatabale

```
$('#tbexport').DataTable({
    ....
        "destroy": true,
    ....
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need both of below-listed script in your application. just select one

script src='includes/js/dataTables/datatables.min.js'
script src='includes/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js'

it can also be that you calling the dataTable twice